# Get result view with formatter programmattically

Tags: views, 8

Example a view with show fields:

[image]

I want retrive array result like this:

```
[
  [title,
   date_start
   data_end
   ...
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$view->result` to get the filtered rows, `$view-field` for the fields, on which you can use the methods `getValue()` for the field value and `render()` for the formatted field as render array.

An example:

```
use Drupal\views\Views;

  $values = [];
  $view = views::getview('view_example');
  if ($view) {
    $view->execute();
    foreach ($view->result as $rid => $row) {
      foreach ($view->field as $fid => $field ) {
        $values[$rid][$fid . '-value'] = $field->getValue($row);
        $values[$rid][$fid . '-render'] = $field->render($row);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: ! i try, THZ :D

Comment: This worked for me. One thing to note is that tokens and some field formaters don't work with render, `$field->advancedRender()` works though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field "global text" and add all fields inside of this field for show all fields that you have in one field

I hope can help you

Comment: Unfortunately no, I need the fields in code formatted...
it is impossible that you can not do

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

1. Exclude all the fields from
   display except the last one.
2. Be sure to have the Token Module installed and enabled.
3. Rewrite the output of the last field with the tokens of the needed fields and your array formatting: `[[title],...]`
   The available patterns should be visible below.
4. Adjust the output to your needs and through the rewrite of the last field with the tokens or the formatting of the excluded fields (perhaps necessary for the format of dates and strings).

Comment: No, i want use result in php. I use View:getView for retrive THE view

Comment: What are you "getting" in PHP so far. So what happens when you print it?

Comment: Return entities, not formatted fields.
I remember correctly or drupal 7 returned formatted files wit view_get_view ?

Comment: No, but it's possible to get the view's result. Drupal 8 comes with "views_get_view_result" https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.module/function/views_get_view_result/8.2.x Does that help? This should do the same.

Comment: Haven't seen the answer above, sorry.