# Retrieve field value in a view twig

Tags: views, theming, 8, entities

I would retrieve the value of a field of the first row, like this:

```
rows[0].field_name..
```

but the 'array is too large and kint breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up the structure of the view result in your question [Get result view with formatter programmattically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219475/get-result-view-with-formatter-programmattically). (there was no feedback, did it work?)

If you want to use this in twig, it would look like this:

```
{{ view.field.field_name.value(view.result[0]) }}
```