# How to print fields value in views-view.html.twig in drupal 8

Tags: views, theming

How to print fields value in views-view.html.twig
I have created a `views-view.html.twig` file for my view `slider_3`.
The template name is 'views-view--slider_3.html.twig'
The view formatting is done by this template, but I need a field is come at begging position of the view:

`<div class="slider-3-main">{{ rows.required_field }}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if title %}
    {{ title }}
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}`

How can be the field will written to display at `{{ rows.required_field }}`

Comment: I have created a ECK (https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) field in content type field as "Entity reference".
Now need to print this field in a view. How can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a field value of the first result row `view.result[0]` use the method [EntityField::getValue](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21EntityField.php/function/EntityField%3A%3AgetValue/8.4.x) of the view field:

```
{{ view.field.field_example.getvalue(view.result[0]) }}
```

Comment: Waw this is amazing, its working. Thanks a lot for this.
Could you please explain by which manner you have got this solution using `EntityField::getValue`

Comment: From the php code, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219537/47547