# How do I convert the result fro views_get_view_result() to an array?

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I am getting an object from `views_get_view_result()`.

```
Array
(
 [0] => Drupal\views\ResultRow Object
    (
        [_entity] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node Object
            (
                [in_preview] => 
                [values:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [vid] => Array
                            (
                                [x-default] => 9
                            )

                        [langcode] => Array
                            (
                                [x-default] => en
                            )

                        [revision_uid] => Array
                            (
                                [x-default] => 1
                            )

                        [revision_timestamp] => Array
                            (
                                [x-default] => 1508904645
                            )

                        [revision_log] => Array
                            (
                                [x-default] => 
                            )
```

How do I convert it to an array? My objective is to get the content types fields values. In an entity object there is `toArray()` to achieve this, but it doesn't work for what `views_get_view_result()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the entity you are looking for:

```
$node = $row->_entity;
```

And the field values:

```
$values = $node->toArray();
```

These are all of the values from the node, however if you want the results from the fields configured in the Views UI, see [Get result view with formatter programmattically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219475/get-result-view-with-formatter-programmattically/219537#219537)

Comment: It doesn't work. There isn't such thing as toArray()

Comment: It's hard to debug your code without knowing it, but suppose you have the rows in `$rows`, then loop over them with `foreach ($rows as $row)` and then you should be able to find the entity of each row in `$row`.

Comment: It works. Is there any way to do this without looping the object array?

Comment: Yes, you can use array functions, but this is more a php question.