# How to get a rendered output field from view object programatically

Tags: views, 8

I can get the value of the field from the view object like this:

```
foreach ($view['#view']->result as $row){
      $field_slide_banner = $row->_entity->get('field_slider_banner')->getValue();     
    }
```

However, in this case I get the target_id of the referenced image file, but I need to get the full rendered output data, which depends on format that I set for this field at the view display, for example, that should be the URL of the image in my case.

In other words, I want to be able to get final output data or HTML markup programmatically for any view field from the given row of executed view object.

Comment: To render the field as configured in Views UI use a render method of the field handler (`render()` or `advancedRender()`), see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219537/47547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
foreach ($view->result as $row) {
  // Change the full view with your view mode.
  $render_array = $row->_entity->field_slider_banner->view('full');
  $field_slider_banner_markup = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($render_array);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the following code.

```
foreach ($view->result as $id => $row) {
  $my_field_value = $view->style_plugin->getFieldValue($id, 'field_name');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and I can see the full output of the field. Also, I have found other solution, where it is possible to get field value without surrounding markup like this: 
$result = $view->style_plugin->getFieldValue($id, $field);
where id is the row number and field is the name of the field.

Comment: i'm glad that help, i will add the second way to my answer, in case someone needs it. thanks .

Comment: Pretty sure this is not the answer; this is how to get a field from the primary views entity. i.e. an entity field; not a views field.

Comment: If you are sure itsn't the answer add one ;)

Comment: Here you go: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308755/how-to-get-a-rendered-views-field-value-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment391799_308755 - please don't go around down-voting my answers just because you don't understand them. :(

Comment: you are not respectful sir this is not the way we comment on open source community, people here contribe to community from their own time, if it's not the what you are looking for ask another question, and answer it people who asked the original question the answer worked for them so no need to play the smart person in the room okay