# Programmatically get the results of a view

Tags: views, 8, users, cron, group

Using the group module in D8, I have the below view with machine name: `group_members_per_group`

[image: group members per group]

**Machine Name of**:

- (Member account) User: Full Name is: `field_user_full_name`
- (Member account) User: Phone Number is: `field_user_phone_number`

**The above view has the below results:**

[image: View results]

On cron run, and while Looping through all rows of the view results, I want to get `for each` row the `field_user_phone_number` value so I can use it with other code.

**So I wrote:**

```
function my_module_cron() {

// Get and loop through the View `group_members_per_group`
//$args = [$gid];
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('group_members_per_group');
//$view->setArguments($args);
$view->setDisplay('default');
$view->execute();

// Get the results of the view.
$view_result = $view->result;

// Check if the view is not empty and return results.
if (!empty($view_result)) {

// If the view returns results...
foreach ($view->result as $row) {

// Get the full name value.
$name = $row->field_user_full_name;


// check the result output for testing only.
\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t($name));
  }
 }
}
```

However, on cron run, I am receiving the below error:

> Notice: Undefined property: Drupal\views\ResultRow::$field_user_full_name in my_module_cron() (line 103 of modules\custom\my_module\my_module.module).
>       my_module_cron(Object)
>       call_user_func('my_module_cron', Object) (Line: 316)
>       Drupal\ultimate_cron\Entity\CronJob->invokeCallback() (Line: 459)
>       Drupal\ultimate_cron\Entity\CronJob->run(Object) (Line: 24)
>       Drupal\ultimate_cron\Controller\JobController->runCronJob(Object)
>       call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
>       Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 582)
>       …
>       …

Line 103 in the error is:

```
$name = $row->field_user_full_name;
```

Comment: You need to combine $view->result with $view->field, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219475/get-result-view-with-formatter-programmattically

Comment: @4k4 I ran through this link while searching online for answers, but did not understand how to use as for my use case! Can you please give a real example on how to use this combination ?

Answer (score 7):

You can not get the value of field directly from row result.
You can get it by accessing to the entity like the following:
**Option1**

```
  foreach ($view->result as $id => $result) {
    $node = $result->_entity;
    // Get the full name value.
    $name = $node->get('field_user_full_name')->value;
    // check the result output for testing only.
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t($name));
  }
```

Or by loop through the fields like the following:
**Option2:**

```
foreach ($view->result as $id => $row) {
      foreach ($view->field as $fid => $field) {
        if ($fid == 'field_user_full_name') {
          //Get the full name value.
          $name = $field->getValue($row);
          // check the result output for testing only.
          \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t($name));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Also, wrong, as are all the answers here. These are simply describing how to get a field from the base entity returned by the View. These are not the fields of the view.

Comment: if you find those answers wrong, step up and post one correct people here just trying to help so they don't need those kind of comments

Comment: that's an odd comment. I certainly appreciate it when people post that something is wrong; that way i don't waste time trying it (as i did with all these answers). And knowing something is wrong doesn't mean you know the right answer - i am still looking.

Comment: posted correct answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the '$result->_entity' was empty, so I had to get the value from the '$result->_object' :

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_view__YOUR_VIEW_ID(array &$variables): void {
  foreach ($variables['view']->result as $result) {
    $node = $result->_object->getEntity();
    $title = $node->get('title')->getValue()[0]['value'];
    $body = $node->get('body')->getValue()[0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot

Comment: In fact, `$result->_entity` is empty when the preprocessed view is rendering data from a Search API index and not rendering standard content.

Answer (score 2):

I had to re-ask this question to be more clear here: [How to get a rendered views field value programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/308755/how-to-get-a-rendered-views-field-value-programmatically)

@4k4 pointed me towards the right solution for getting a value from a field in a view:

```
foreach ($view->result as $rid => $row) {
  $type[$row->nid] = $view->field['my_views_field']->advancedRender($row)->__toString();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, odd this is down-voted when no reason added. Not to mention it is the correct answer.

Comment: Error: Call to a member function __toString() on string