# How can I get a field in hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables)?

Tags: 8, views

Is there a way to get a field from the view in the `hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables)`?

```php
$rows = $variables['rows'];
foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
  // $row['field_name']?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find the field handlers you have configured in the Fields list in `$view->field`. A field handler has methods like `getValue()`, `render()` and `advancedRender()`, which accept as argument the row variable:

Example:

```
$view = $variables['view'];
$rows = $variables['rows'];
foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
  $field_value = $view->field['field_name']->getValue($row);
}
```

See also [Get result view with formatter programmattically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219475/get-result-view-with-formatter-programmattically)